# Open multiple http links in browser

Tags: org-mode

Using org-mode, I can open a single url with `Cco` on it.

But if I have a list of them like:

```
- http://www.cnn.com
- http://www.example.com
```

How can I tell it to open all of them in different tabs?

I use Firefox. Marking all and applying Cco would just run the last one.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [multiple-cursors](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el) package!  When you have all lines in your region you can use `mc/mark-lines` to create cursors for each line.  Move your cursors onto the URL and use your usual command to open the link (sounds like `C-c o`?).  Answer 'yes' when asked whether to use the command for all cursors.

Multiple cursors offers a variety of other approaches to create cursors (`mc/mark-next-like-this`, `mc/mark-all-like-this`, `mc/mark-all-like-this-dwim`, etc.).  Play around with them a little bit to decide what's comfortable.  I have a selection of mc commands bound to `C-c m` for convenience.

Comment: For some reason, I don't have `mc/mark-lines`? Only `mc/mark-next-lines` which doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I can do `mc/edit-beginnings-of-lines`